# New profile created from AD and appears in Sharepoint admin but Old details come up when picking the user to add to lists

Tags: 2010, user-profile, active-directory

I've changed a users details in AD. The new profile shows in SharePoint admin, the old profile doesn't but when you try and find the new details to add them to a list etc the old profile is the only one there.

Suz

Answer (score 2):

1. Please check if "User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" is running. [Full Synchronization Job](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2703630/user-profile-to-sharepoint-full-synchronization-job-stops-computing-membership)
2. If user's login name has changed then try running Move-SPUser command. [Move-SPUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx)

Comment: Also, you may try [link](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/12/updating-sharepoint-2010-user-information/) with appropriate changes (title part).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the User Profile to User Info List synchronization is not working or is delayed. Can you have the user in question visit the site and take some action, like edit an item or upload a document? It should refresh the info in about 15 minutes.

If not there are some options for forcing the synchronization of the UIL from the User Profile.